# Discord.py rewrite bot doesn't work in heroku but works locally

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

The bot worked in local but not working when hosted in Heroku it faces errors.

This is the log file from Heroku

```
heroku logs --tail
2019-02-14T08:47:54.816954+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with  command `python bot.py`
2019-02-14T08:47:55.393447+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-14T08:48:01.249027+00:00 app[worker.1]: We have logged in as Sheogorath#1014
2019-02-15T09:05:48.819190+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Cycling
2019-02-15T09:05:48.894223+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-02-15T09:05:49.936542+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-02-15T09:05:50.060234+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-02-15T09:05:53.405715+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`
2019-02-15T09:05:54.392209+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-15T09:06:01.127733+00:00 app[worker.1]: We have logged in as Sheogorath#1014
2019-02-16T09:33:52.034802+00:00 app[worker.1]: bot-testing: LordDraagon#7410: LordDraagon: hello uncle sheo
2019-02-16T09:33:52.034995+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_message
2019-02-16T09:33:52.042092+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-16T09:33:52.042231+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
2019-02-16T09:33:52.042234+00:00 app[worker.1]: yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
2019-02-16T09:33:52.042299+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 75, in on_message
2019-02-16T09:33:52.042302+00:00 app[worker.1]: await replyBack(message)
2019-02-16T09:33:52.042366+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 19, in replyBack
2019-02-16T09:33:52.042368+00:00 app[worker.1]: await message.channel.send('Greetings! Salutations! Welcome! Now go away. Leave. Run. Or die.')
2019-02-16T09:33:52.042450+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'send'
2019-02-16T09:33:59.644154+00:00 app[worker.1]: bot-testing: LordDraagon#7410: LordDraagon: sheogorath.member_count()
2019-02-16T09:33:59.647064+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_message
2019-02-16T09:33:59.647834+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-16T09:33:59.648005+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
2019-02-16T09:33:59.648008+00:00 app[worker.1]: yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
2019-02-16T09:33:59.648147+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 82, in on_message
2019-02-16T09:33:59.648149+00:00 app[worker.1]: await getDetails(message,message.guild)
2019-02-16T09:33:59.648339+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'guild'
2019-02-16T09:38:43.636447+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `heroku run` by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T09:38:47.076943+00:00 heroku[run.2120]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T09:38:46.941395+00:00 heroku[run.2120]: Awaiting client
2019-02-16T09:38:47.234998+00:00 heroku[run.2120]: Starting process with command `heroku run`
2019-02-16T09:38:51.406757+00:00 heroku[run.2120]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-16T09:38:51.387399+00:00 heroku[run.2120]: Process exited with status 127
2019-02-16T09:40:47.905773+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Cycling
2019-02-16T09:40:47.986939+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-02-16T09:40:49.543819+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-02-16T09:40:49.752067+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-02-16T09:40:51.106330+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`
2019-02-16T09:40:51.679966+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T09:40:55.966779+00:00 app[worker.1]: We have logged in as Sheogorath#1014
2019-02-16T09:54:18.362670+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `pip` by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T09:54:23.024305+00:00 heroku[run.9771]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T09:54:23.004772+00:00 heroku[run.9771]: Awaiting client
2019-02-16T09:54:23.306227+00:00 heroku[run.9771]: Starting process with command `pip`
2019-02-16T09:54:28.935863+00:00 heroku[run.9771]: Process exited with status 0
2019-02-16T09:54:29.145616+00:00 heroku[run.9771]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-16T09:57:21.693571+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]` by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T09:57:25.243366+00:00 heroku[run.4339]: Awaiting client
2019-02-16T09:57:25.560838+00:00 heroku[run.4339]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]`
2019-02-16T09:57:26.294896+00:00 heroku[run.4339]: State changed from starting to up
 2019-02-16T09:57:49.117673+00:00 heroku[run.4339]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-16T09:57:49.098072+00:00 heroku[run.4339]: Process exited with status 1
2019-02-16T10:00:29.850598+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `pip install --upgrade pip` by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T10:00:33.959344+00:00 heroku[run.7180]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T10:00:33.977943+00:00 heroku[run.7180]: Awaiting client
2019-02-16T10:00:34.331603+00:00 heroku[run.7180]: Starting process with command `pip install --upgrade pip`
2019-02-16T10:00:42.879420+00:00 heroku[run.7180]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-16T10:00:42.858327+00:00 heroku[run.7180]: Process exited with status 0
2019-02-16T10:02:30.329208+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]` by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T10:02:35.025887+00:00 heroku[run.3241]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T10:02:34.960600+00:00 heroku[run.3241]: Awaiting client
2019-02-16T10:02:35.273280+00:00 heroku[run.3241]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]`
2019-02-16T10:03:14.623433+00:00 heroku[run.3241]: Process exited with status 1
2019-02-16T10:03:15.107022+00:00 heroku[run.3241]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-16T10:04:01.365397+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py` by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T10:04:04.717198+00:00 heroku[run.4162]: Awaiting client
2019-02-16T10:04:05.009961+00:00 heroku[run.4162]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py`
2019-02-16T10:04:05.498337+00:00 heroku[run.4162]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T10:04:12.417782+00:00 heroku[run.4162]: Process exited with status 0
2019-02-16T10:04:13.653844+00:00 heroku[run.4162]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-16T10:04:45.918379+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]` by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T10:04:50.380315+00:00 heroku[run.4892]: Awaiting client
2019-02-16T10:04:50.657792+00:00 heroku[run.4892]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T10:04:50.696282+00:00 heroku[run.4892]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]`
2019-02-16T10:05:09.548908+00:00 heroku[run.4892]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-16T10:05:09.531050+00:00 heroku[run.4892]: Process exited with status 1
2019-02-16T10:05:23.172659+00:00 app[worker.1]: bot-testing: LordDraagon#7410: LordDraagon: sheogorath.member_count()
2019-02-16T10:05:23.172801+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_message
2019-02-16T10:05:23.176751+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-16T10:05:23.176842+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
2019-02-16T10:05:23.176845+00:00 app[worker.1]: yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
2019-02-16T10:05:23.176901+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 82, in on_message
2019-02-16T10:05:23.176903+00:00 app[worker.1]: await getDetails(message,message.guild)
2019-02-16T10:05:23.176969+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'guild'
2019-02-16T10:10:15.048230+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to worker@0:Free by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T10:10:15.359585+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to down
2019-02-16T10:10:16.387560+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-02-16T10:10:16.481690+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-02-16T10:16:04.912170+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/rewrite.zip` by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T10:16:08.855491+00:00 heroku[run.9325]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T10:16:08.841552+00:00 heroku[run.9325]: Awaiting client
2019-02-16T10:16:09.148281+00:00 heroku[run.9325]: Starting process with command `python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/rewrite.zip`
2019-02-16T10:16:27.380488+00:00 heroku[run.9325]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-16T10:16:27.365861+00:00 heroku[run.9325]: Process exited with status 0
2019-02-16T10:19:50.688221+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to worker@1:Free by user buddhiadikari@live.com
2019-02-16T10:19:55.511089+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`
2019-02-16T10:19:56.172891+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-02-16T10:20:02.222063+00:00 app[worker.1]: We have logged in as Sheogorath#1014
2019-02-16T10:20:21.514609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=sheogorath-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=97c7acd9-af88-4bdf-b367-6274f91a6aeb fwd="112.135.12.166" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-02-16T10:20:58.490018+00:00 app[worker.1]: bot-testing: LordDraagon#7410: LordDraagon: hello uncle sheo
2019-02-16T10:20:58.490490+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_message
2019-02-16T10:20:58.492711+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-16T10:20:58.492816+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
2019-02-16T10:20:58.492818+00:00 app[worker.1]: yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
2019-02-16T10:20:58.492855+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 75, in on_message
2019-02-16T10:20:58.492857+00:00 app[worker.1]: await replyBack(message)
2019-02-16T10:20:58.492892+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 19, in replyBack
2019-02-16T10:20:58.492895+00:00 app[worker.1]: await message.channel.send('Greetings! Salutations! Welcome! Now go away. Leave. Run. Or die.')
2019-02-16T10:20:58.492977+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'send'
2019-02-16T10:21:08.406843+00:00 app[worker.1]: bot-testing: LordDraagon#7410: LordDraagon: sheogorath.member_count()
2019-02-16T10:21:08.408965+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_message
2019-02-16T10:21:08.409831+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-16T10:21:08.409892+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
2019-02-16T10:21:08.409895+00:00 app[worker.1]: yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
2019-02-16T10:21:08.409971+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 82, in on_message
2019-02-16T10:21:08.409974+00:00 app[worker.1]: await getDetails(message,message.guild)
2019-02-16T10:21:08.410030+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

I have my requirments.txt file with these dependencies included .

> git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py
>
> retry
>
> asyncio

And I have this in my procfile

> worker: python bot.py

As for my knowledge I think Heroku can't install the discordpy rewrite version for my project. I've less knowledge in using Heroku but I hope I have integrated Heroku correctly

Comment: it looks like the error might be in your actual code based on the logs

Comment: but those errors does not appear when i run the project locally and have tested with discord while running locally

Comment: Heroku is using the async branch instead of the rewrite branch (add a line that logs `discord.__version__` to see this for yourself).  Other people have had the same problem, you might look around at their questions

Answer (score 1):

In requirements.txt remove everything and write

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite
dnspython==1.16.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
```

To download the rewrite branch. i don't really know if its because of using async branch on heroku about the errors but try this is may help out.

Comment: Also this is tested by me because I use rewrite branch commands and host it on heroku and its perfectly fine

Comment: **Edit:** i have looked the error and it tells me you wrote the command for rewrite branch and actually used async branch to host it in heroku so it abviously gives error

So do what i said to use rewrite branch for heroku

Comment: Also u don't need to put asyncio it installs by itself in heroku

Answer (score 1):

The error is `AttributeError: Ignoring exception in on_message`, `'Channel' object has no attribute 'send'`, `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'guild'`.

Next you should fix your `requirements.txt`. I used Heroku, and the code was perfect, it has no errors, but it wont run. Why? Because `requirements.txt` from `pip freeze > requirements.txt` won't work at all. and you don't give the code or the url to the code, so how can we debug it?